# SOAP Webservice call from .NET Core application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, soap

I currently have the following code

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;

namespace ProjectName.Services
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://domainName/WS")]
    interface WS
    {
        [OperationContract()]
        string GetChart(string id, bool Small, string ChartType);
    }

    public class ChartService : IChartService
    {
        public void GetChart()
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            var Uri = new Uri("http://siteUrl/ws/serviceName.asmx");
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(Uri);
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WS>(binding, endpoint);
            var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var result = serviceClient.GetChart("123456", true, "V");
            channelFactory.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Which (I pressume) is correctly calling the Web Service, however, it's throwing the following exception:

```
   "OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'GetChartResponse' and namespace 'http://domainName'. 
   Found node type 'Element' with name 'GetChartResponse' and namespace 'http://domainName/WS/'"
```

But adding  '/WS' to the namespace (which is the actual namespace of the service I'm trying to call) throws:

```
   "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://domainName/WS/WS/GetChart.\n   
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap11ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()\n   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()\n   
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocol.SetContext(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)\n   
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)"
```

How can I either set the expected namespace or make it so the interface name isn't added to the SOAPAction header?

Comment: Are you positive that address exists, that looks like Soap could not actually find the endpoint, also why do you have two WS shouldn't you have one?

Comment: Am positive that `http://domainName/WS` exists. I'm unfamiliar with SOAP service calls so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but what do you mean by having two WS?

Comment: That might exists but your calling `http://domainName/WS/WS/GetChart`